# What are the types of problems TensorFlow can help solve?

Tags: tensorflow

The [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) home page describes its purpose as 'a software library for numerical computation'. Looking through the sample problems it looks like a problem is always formulated as follows:

1. Input
2. Model parameters
3. Desired output

Given some training data for 1) and 3), 2) can be computed.

I can see how this can be used to create bots, self-driving cars, image classifiers etc.

Given the broad definition of 'numerical computation', am I missing a class of other problems this can be used for? Can this be used for, say, more classical numerical computations such as the airflow around an aircraft or deformation of a structure under stress? Do you have any examples of how these classical problems would have to be formulated to fit the form above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[A nice discussion](https://www.quora.com/What-problems-in-artificial-intelligence-cannot-be-addressed-using-artificial-neural-networks-and-what-of-using-deep-belief-networks) on what artificial neural networks could do, the fact that our brain is a neural network might imply that eventually an artificial neural network will be able to to the same tasks.

Some more examples of artificial neural networks used today: [music creation](http://web.mit.edu/felixsun/www/neural-music.html), [image based location](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/600889/google-unveils-neural-network-with-superhuman-ability-to-determine-the-location-of-almost/), page rank, [google voice](https://research.googleblog.com/2015/08/the-neural-networks-behind-google-voice.html), [stock trade predictions](http://www.trade2win.com/boards/trading-systems/89656-can-neural-network-trade-markets-effectively.html), [nasa star classifiaction](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002A%26A...385.1119P), [traffic management](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/Workshops/1993/WS-93-04/WS93-04-012.pdf)
Some fields i know of but do not have a good reference for:
optical quantum mechanics test set-up generator
medical diagnosis, [reference](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20000101656.pdf) only about safety
The Sharp LogiCook microwave oven, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Tarassenko), [nasa mention](https://ti.arc.nasa.gov/publications/1117/download/)

I think there are many millions of "problems" that can be solved with an ANN, deciding on the data representation (input,output) will be a challenge for some of these. some useful and useless examples i have been thinking about:

- home thermostat that learns your wishes with certain weather types.
- bakery production prediction
- recognize go-stones on a board and map their locations
- personal activity guesser and turn on appropriate device.
- recognize person based on mouse movement

Given the right data and network these examples will work.
Dad has a pc controlling the heating system back home, i trained a network based on his 10years of heating data (outside temp, inside temp, humidity etc.) unfortunately i am not allowed to hook it up.

My aunt and uncle have a bakery, based on 6years of sales data i trained a network predicting how many breads and buns they should make. It showed me how important the correct inputs are. first i used the day of the year but when i switched to day of the week i saw a 15% increase in accuracy.

Currently i am working on a network that will detect a [go board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29) in a given image and map all 361 locations telling me if there is a black, white or no stone present.

Two examples that showed me how much information can be stored in a single neuron and of different ways to represent data:
[Image example](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/image_regression.html), [neuron example](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/autoencoder.html) (unfortunately you have to train both examples yourself so give them a little time.)

On to your example airflow around an aircraft.
I know none to nothing about airflow calculations and my try would be a really huge 3D input layer where you can "draw" an airplane and the direction and speed of the airflow.
It might work but it will require a tremendous amount of computation power, somebody knowing more about this specific topic probably knows a more abstract way of representing the data resulting in a more manageable network.
[This nasa paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20000101656.pdf)  talks about a neural network for calculating airflow around a wing. Unfortunately i do not understand what kind of input they use, maybe it is more clear to you.

Comment: Brilliant answer, accepted. Good luck with the things you are working on.

Comment: Very nice answer!!